# Generating a keytab for Active Directory user?

Tags: active-directory, kerberos

I am relatively new to Kerberos, we have integrated Active Directory for authentication. I.E. When we do kinit ad_user, we get a valid TGT.

Now I want to run the application as a user in headless mode as application accepts Keytab. Is there a way using which we can generate a keytab for a particular user of Active Directory?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [Creating Kerberos Keytab Files Compatible with Active Directory](http://www.itadmintools.com/2011/07/creating-kerberos-keytab-files.html).

On windows host:

```
ktpass ﻿/princ username@MYDOMAIN.COM /pass password /ptype KRB5_NT_PRINCIPAL /out username.keytab
```

Kinit using keytab:

```
kinit username@MYDOMAIN.COM -k -t username.keytab
```